# running vb.net in a new thread

Tags: vb.net

how do I force a particular set of vb.net codes to run in a new thread or process.?

Edit 1: I am trying TTS in vb.net but whenever click the play button , The whole program freezes and I cannot do anything else until the speech is over

Comment: I dunno, how do you? If you ask a proper question (at least include a question mark), maybe somebody could answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment below you mention the library you are using and that changes this whole answer.

**Answer to your problem:**
In your case since you are using the SAPI.SpVoice library you don't need to do any work related to spinning up background threads and such since that object support asynchronous playback.  Check out the arguments of the Speak method.  Here is the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723609(v=vs.85).aspx

**Answer to your question as it is posed:**
The simplest method is to use a background worker process to run some code.  This will allow your program to run some long process and not block the UI thread.  The background worker even provides events to notify your UI thread of it's progress.

Here is an link to MSDN  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

The background worker is a simple way to spin off some work onto another thread, there are other tools for more complex scenarios.  In essence you create an instance of a background worker object and add your long-running code to a function that is created to handle it's DoWork event.  There are ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events that should be handled as well.  There are methods that can be called to cancel the process.  The MSDN link above provides a couple of good complete code examples.

Comment: Type 'BackgroundWorker' is not defined. how do i define it ?

Comment: @abc: There is a complete code example for using `BackgroundWorker` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Once a background process has started how can i force it quit or pause ?

Comment: In your case, using the SAPI object you can call the Pause method.  Take a look at the documentation link I provide at the top my answer.  Make sure you Call the Speak method with the SVSFlagsAsync argument.  In a background worker thread you have enable cancelling by setting the property WorkerSupportsCancellation=True and then periodically check in your DoWork handler the worker property CancellationPending to see if it is true.  If it is, you set the DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel = True and exit the sub.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the "set of codes" into a method and dump it onto the ThreadPool

```
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf MyMethod)
```

Answer (score 1):

the ThreadPool suggestion worked for me for a WP7 Silverlight app:

```
  Private Sub AddAnagrams()
    ClearAnagramsList()
    UpdateAnagramsCount() 'update the count first, then add the items
    ShowCalculating(True)
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf UpdateAnagramsOnUIthread)
  End Sub

  Private Sub UpdateAnagramsOnUIthread()
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(AddressOf UpdateAnagrams)
  End Sub

  Private Sub UpdateAnagrams()
    ListAnagrams.ItemsSource = _Combinator.CombinedItems 'this is a virtualized datasource
    ShowCalculating(False)
  End Sub

  Private Sub ShowCalculating(ByVal flag As Boolean)
    LblCalculating.Visibility = If(flag, Windows.Visibility.Visible, Windows.Visibility.Collapsed)
  End Sub
```